# Undo simple javascript event - removing curly braces from textbox

Tags: javascript, textbox

I'm attempting to add and remove curly braces around a `textbox` value with javascript.

What I have done so far is to add them correctly but I'm at a loss for removing them on `uncheck`. Here is my code:

```
 <script>

 Toggle();
 function Toggle(){
 if (document.form1.icd.checked){
 document.form1.amln.value= "{" + document.form1.amln.value + "}";
 } 


 }
 </script>

<input type="checkbox" name="icd" value="icd" onClick="Toggle();" /> 

<input type="text" name="amln" id="amln" />
```

Comment: where are you removing the braces? is there an `else` statement that's missing from your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Match Beginning and End**

```
var tb = document.form1.amln;
tb.value = tb.value.replace(/[{}]/g,"")
```

**Remove any { and }**

```
var tb = document.form1.amln;
tb.value = tb.value.replace(/[{}]/g,"");
```

**Combine it with the check**

```
function addBraces() {
    var fm = document.form1,
        tb = fm.amln;
    tb.value = tb.value.replace(/[{}]/g,"");  //doing it here in case {} already exist
    if (fm.icd.checked) {
        tb.value = "{" + tb.value + "}";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to upvote the best answer @Jeff - I'd +1 you again if I could.  Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to also get rid of any curly braces the user typed in (or just not have to worry about it)?  If so, a few simple regexes should work:

```
var tb = document.form1.amln;
tb.value = tb.value.replace(/\{/g).replace(/\}/g);
```

Comment: @epascarello - I may be crazy, but wouldn't /\{\}/ match both braces one after the other?  I figured two replaces would be easiest.

Comment: `tb.value.replace(/^\{|\}$/g,"")` Use the power of OR. And if you do not care about beginning and end: `replace(/[{}]/g,"")`

Comment: @epascarello - that's worthy of its own answer - post it and I'll +1

Comment: @epascarello That's the way to do it. Beat me to it.

Comment: Thank guys, that fixed it epascarello!

Comment: @AdamRackis A long time ago I (as an exercise) decoded [this](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) regexp... Try it and you will learn a lot. :)

Comment: @some  :-O who would do such a thing?!

Comment: @AdamRackis Anyone who wants to master regular expressions! By decoding it you will find some more advanced ways... I know it looks huge, but it actually boils down to a few patters that is repeated. I did learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the braces, use:

```
function Toggle() {
    var form = document.form1;
    var field = form.amln;

    if (form.icd.checked) {
        field.value = "{" + field.value + "}";
    } else {
        field.value = field.value.replace(/(^\{|\}*$)/g, '');
    }
}
```

If want to remove only the first of each leading or trailing brace, you may need to do something more complicated.

```
field.replace(/\{/, '').split('').reverse().join('').replace(/\}/, '').split('').reverse().join('');
```

The efficiency of this sort of operation is probably not the best, but if you are working with small strings, it probably doesn't matter.